# Cannot connect externally to a docker container running CherryPy server

Tags: python, docker, cherrypy

I have a simple CherryPy server running on a Docker container, and I cannot access it externally. I run it using `docker run -p 8181:8181 image-name`. It starts up just fine and I see the normal server log. If I try a curl (`curl localhost:8181`) from inside the container, I get the "Hello World" response. If I try it from my machine I get `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`. What am I doing wrong? Is there any configuration I missed?

Server code:

```
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld(), '/', {'global': {'server.socket_port': 8181}})
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7.13

RUN mkdir -p /opt/server

WORKDIR /opt/server
ADD . /opt/server
VOLUME /opt/server

RUN apt-get update \
&&  apt-get install -y \
    python-setuptools \
    libopenblas-dev \
    gfortran \
    vim \
    curl \
    telnet \
    wget \
&&  pip install --upgrade pip \
&&  pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8181

CMD python server.py
```

requirements.txt

```
bottle==0.12.13
daemon
cherrypy==8.9.1
ipython==5
lockfile
numpy
psutil
python-daemon
python-dateutil
rocket
scikit-learn==0.18.1
scipy
matplotlib
```

PS: Maybe relevant to the question I'm using the Docker client with version `17.03.1-ce-mac12`, and I'm on a Mac ;)

EDIT: Added requirements.txt

Comment: I can't replicate because I don't have the requirements.txt so two questions:
are you curling http://localhost:8181? Can you run `docker logs` on the container? Any results there?

Comment: Hi, Mano, I added the requirements.txt contents, there's a lot of clutter there, but, I suspect that If I leave only cherrypy I'll get the same results. I'll try that. I can run docker logs but I only get output when I curl localhost:8181 from inside the container. And yes, I'm curling localhost:8181 both inside and outside the container.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not a cherrypy expert. However, it looks like you have to designate a host as well, to make sure you're listening to the right incoming address. This works for me:

```
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld(), '/', {'global': {'server.socket_host':'0.0.0.0','server.socket_port': 8181}})
```

Comment: I'm having a really slow download time with docker, but I'll keep you posted as I try your solution. Thank you :)

Comment: `'server.socket_host':'0.0.0.0'` was key